# RecursiveIteratorIterator no listing file that are the same size

Tags: php, search, directory

I have this code

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
$files = array();
$notAllowedExtension = array('jpg', 'vtr', 'html', 'htm' );

foreach($iterator as $file){

if(!in_array($file->getExtension(), $notAllowedExtension) && !$file->isDir())

$files[filemtime($file->getPathname())] = $file->getPathname();
}

sort($files);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($files, true) . "</pre>";
```

I have noticed something quite strange. Using this `echo "<pre>" . print_r($files, true) . "</pre>";` U cab see the result of the array. Great.

If I have the following:

- V001 - Test File.mp4   (FILE SIZE, 3.25MB)
- V002 - Test File.mp4   (FILE SIZE, 7.55MB)
- V003 - Test File.mp4   (FILE SIZE, 4.45MB)

All the above is shown in the array. However, if I have the following:

- V001 - Test File.mp4   (FILE SIZE, **3.25MB**)
- V002 - Test File.mp4   (FILE SIZE, **3.25MB**)
- V003 - Test File.mp4   (FILE SIZE, **3.25MB**)

It only shows 1 file, normally the last one. The difference would be that the file sizes are the same.

Is there a solution as I know that in the future there is a good chance that some of the files with be the same size.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not problem of size, but of index which is time:

```
$files[filemtime($file->getPathname())] = $file->getPathname();
```

Apparently these files have the same time. You should keep time as value not index:

```
$files[] = array(
  'time' => filemtime($file->getPathname()),
  'name' =>$file->getPathname()
);
```

and then use `usort` if you want to sort by time

Comment: Hmm, I replaced `$files[filemtime($file->getPathname())] = $file->getPathname();` with `$files[] = array(
  'time' => filemtime($file->getPathname()),
  'name' =>$file->getPathname();
);` and it is not working at all. Did I miss something.

Thank you for letting me know that it was the time.

Comment: Ok, No I have an issue because the output look different.

My code looked like this `[1435003500] => ./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/V003 - TEST READ ALL - some information.mp4`

Where as your looks like this. Is there anyway to keep the same format so to speak `[0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 1435003500
            [name] => ./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/V001 - TEST READ ALL .mp4
        )`

Comment: There is no way to keep the same format as your original because when times are the same then you lost data. If you do not care about times you can do `$files[] = $file->getPathname();`

Comment: Thank you very much. I think i have a solution thanks to you